# Get most significant decimal digit using Java-8

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to get most significant decimal digit of an integer, and my approach is as follows:

> 1. I am trying to get the total number(count) of digits in the Integer(N);
> 2. I am dividing the Integer(N) by the 1(....count times 0).

**I have done the following code and it works fine, i just want to implement it using java-8 in case if it is possible.**

```
int N = 456778889;
double expo = Math.log10(N);
int expNum = (int)Math.floor(expo)+1;  //gets the total digits in the Integer N
```

Now as I have the total number of digits in the number N, so i can divide the N by 1 followed by total num of zeros, to implemet this 1 followed by X amount of zero my logic is as follows:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("1");
    sb.setLength(expNum);
    String f = sb.toString().replaceAll("[^0-9]","0"); // It makes the 1 followed by X amount of zero that i require to get my MSB
    int mostSigNum = N/(Integer.valueOf(f));
    System.out.println(mostSigNum);
```

---

I know my approach is a bit different as i am mostly using log and other math function, but i really want to do it differently.

Any approach in **java 8** and **stream** type, that can help will be appreciated.

Comment: Not streams but much simpler: `Integer.toString(N).substring(0,1);`

Comment: Why we want everything in java-8?

Comment: I didn't even know you could shift a number using string manipulation. Talk about different (and inefficient)

Comment: If MSB means "most significant byte", then your approach and code is wrong: just use a bit mask and shifting.  If you mean something else, please use English instead of (incorrect) acronyms.

Comment: caution with negative numbers... `log10` will return `NaN`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you stay with your approach of using the rounded value of `log10`, you should also consistently use `Math.pow(10, …)` to go into the other direction, instead of suddenly switching to `String` manipulation.

```
int maxi = (int)(N/Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(N))));
```

As said, in the comments, when you use `String` manipulation, `Integer.toString(N).substring(0,1)` leads to a complete solution. Or, to get the `int` value:

```
int maxi = Character.digit(String.valueOf(N).charAt(0), 10);
```

Comment: very simple solution and easy to understand.

Comment: Obs: the string solution needs some additional work when the number is negative, `log10` will fail at all

Comment: The first solution is more efficient than the latter.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your solution is most simplified according to me and is efficient ,instead of dividing by 10 and doing it until we get no remainder.

```
int N = 456778889;
double expo = Math.log10(N);
int expNum = (int)Math.floor(expo);
```

Now as per stream is considered, we can do following to make the dividing number, which will be 1 followed by X amount of zero, which when used can give us MSB(most significant bit):

```
    String c = IntStream.range(0,expNum).mapToObj(e->"0").collect(Collectors.joining(""));
    String t = "1".concat(c);
    int maxi = N/Integer.parseInt(t);
    System.out.println(maxi);
```

Comment: isn't `(int)Math.floor(d)` the same as `(int)d` for non-negative `d`

Answer (score 0):

In java8 it's very simple

```
public int maxi(int n) {
    return String.valueOf(n)
            .chars()
            .map(i -> i - '0')
            .max()
            .orElse(0);
}

@Test
public void testMaxi() {
    assertEquals(1, maxi(1000));
    assertEquals(7, maxi(7654));
    assertEquals(9, maxi(456778889));
}
```

Comment: My bad; I wasn’t precise enough when I edited the question. It should have been “most significant digit” or “digit at the highest place”. So it’s `findFirst()` rather than `max()`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is dividing by 10 repeatedly until you have a single digit left:

```
int number = 456778889;
int result = IntStream.iterate(number, i -> i / 10) // divide by 10
                      .filter(i -> i < 10)          // filter out if multiple digits
                      .findFirst().getAsInt();      // get the first value
```

Here is the same solution without using a stream:

```
int number = 456778889;
int result;
for (result = number; result >= 10; result /= 10);
```